# WIN 10 PRO Keyboard typed text delayed appearance on screen

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem with Windows 10 Pro and the slow response of text typed on the keyboard appearing on the screen.  The slow response also applies to “processes” or commands selected with the mouse.

I have a Dell, Inispiron 15, laptop that came with WIN 10 Pro Ram,  i7 -2.5 Gig processor, 1TB Disk drive.   Using laptop keyboard and wireless  preinstalled, about  8 months old. with no pre-installed Dell “blote ware”.   I have 8 Gig mouse.  No other changes in performance.

I use the “SLEEP” command rather than a shutdown when I finish a computer work session.  To restart I tap the “power on” button or the “enter” key and WIN10 starts where I put it to “SLEEP”, with no problems.

The problem:  After about the second or third time of waking up from the “SLEEP” mode the response of text typed on the keyboard and commands selected with the mouse begins to slow down.   Specifically, typed text begins to show a lag before it appears on the screen and mouse generated commands also show a lag before the finish of execution.  The lag is not program dependent; typing text into an email, a Word document or any other document has the same delay.   Same applies for mouse commands; selecting an email document to open, tapping “enter” to change web pages or the “save” command in Word – all have the same delay.

The more times the “SLEEP” and restart sequence is preformed the longer the delay becomes. By the 5th or 6th  cycle the delay is several seconds and only about the first 4 or 5  typed characters appear.  Several seconds later the remaining typed characters will appear, but not all characters of a long sentence.

If I “shutdown” instead of “SLEEP” and then restart the delay is not present.   As far as I can tell, even after several hours of use the “typed text appearing on screen delay” has not appeared.

What is causing the delay?

Why does it happen only in “Sleep” mode?

What is the fix for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

just a thought, have you tried to update the bios? i also have an inspiron (newer model) laptop and noticed that the built in dell updater does not include the bios for some reason? I found from their site a newer bios firmware and also an update for the m2 ssd.. give the bios update a shot?